# How to query last restore date in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, restore

Is there a T-SQL query that shows the last restore datetime for a certain database?

Comment: 2nd hit: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1724/when-was-the-last-time-your-sql-server-database-was-restored/

Answer (score 155, accepted):

This will list all "most recent" restores for each database on your server:

```
WITH LastRestores AS
(
SELECT
    DatabaseName = [d].[name] ,
    [d].[create_date] ,
    [d].[compatibility_level] ,
    [d].[collation_name] ,
    r.*,
    RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.Name ORDER BY r.[restore_date] DESC)
FROM master.sys.databases d
LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.[restorehistory] r ON r.[destination_database_name] = d.Name
)
SELECT *
FROM [LastRestores]
WHERE [RowNum] = 1
```

Comment: records in `restorehistory` may be cleaned by `sp_delete_backuphistory`.

Answer (score 18):

The script that can be used is:

```
declare @DB sysname = 'MyDB';
select * from msdb.dbo.restorehistory where destination_database_name = @DB;
```

Answer (score 16):

main table for this purpose is msdb..restorehistory

```
SELECT  [rs].[destination_database_name] ,
        [rs].[restore_date] ,
        [bs].[backup_start_date] ,
        [bs].[backup_finish_date] ,
        [bs].[database_name] AS [source_database_name] ,
        [bmf].[physical_device_name] AS [backup_file_used_for_restore]
FROM    msdb..restorehistory rs
        INNER JOIN msdb..backupset bs ON [rs].[backup_set_id] = [bs].[backup_set_id]
        INNER JOIN msdb..backupmediafamily bmf ON [bs].[media_set_id] = [bmf].[media_set_id]
ORDER BY [rs].[restore_date] DESC
```

[from mssqltips](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1860/identify-when-a-sql-server-database-was-restored-the-source-and-backup-date/)

Comment: +1 that in addition to restore date it returns backup date which was also useful in my case

Answer (score 4):

It will give you the latest refresh date for your DB:

```
use [msdb]
select top 1 * from restorehistory 
where destination_database_name='DB_NAME'
order by restore_history_id desc
```

Comment: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid object name 'restorehistory'.

Answer (score 2):

Adding important information about OS User name and Machine Name:

```
Select Destination_database_name, 
       restore_date,
       database_name as Source_database,
       Physical_device_name as Backup_file_used_to_restore,
       bs.user_name,
       bs.machine_name
from msdb.dbo.restorehistory rh 
  inner join msdb.dbo.backupset bs 
    on rh.backup_set_id=bs.backup_set_id
  inner join msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily bmf 
    on bs.media_set_id =bmf.media_set_id
ORDER BY [rh].[restore_date] DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

> **Is there a T-SQL query that shows the last restore datetime for a certain database?**

Hi, 
I have generated the below script which can give you much more detailed information about your query.

> **Query to get the "Most Recent Restore"  information about the specific database:**

```
WITH MostRecentRestore AS
(
SELECT 
RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RH.Destination_database_name ORDER BY RH.Restore_Date DESC),
RH.Restore_date, 
BS.[database_name] as Source_Database, 
RH.Destination_Database_Name, 
BS.Backup_Start_Date, 
BS.Backup_Finish_Date, 
CASE WHEN RH.restore_type = 'D' THEN 'Database'
  WHEN RH.restore_type = 'F' THEN 'File'
  WHEN RH.restore_type = 'G' THEN 'Filegroup'
  WHEN RH.restore_type = 'I' THEN 'Differential'
  WHEN RH.restore_type = 'L' THEN 'Log'
  WHEN RH.restore_type = 'V' THEN 'Verifyonly'
  WHEN RH.restore_type = 'R' THEN 'Revert'
  ELSE RH.restore_type 
END AS Restore_Type,
RH.[Replace],
RH.[Recovery],
RH.Restore_Date AS Restored_On,
BMF.physical_device_name AS Restored_From,
RF.destination_phys_name AS Current_DB_File_Location,
RH.user_name AS Restored_By,
BS.machine_name,
BS.Server_Name
FROM msdb.dbo.RestoreHistory RH 
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.BackupSet BS ON RH.backup_set_id = BS.backup_set_id
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.restorefile RF ON RH.Restore_History_id = RF.Restore_History_id
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.Backupmediafamily BMF ON bs.media_set_id = bmf.media_set_id
)
SELECT *
FROM MostRecentRestore
WHERE [RowNum] = 1 AND destination_database_name = 'YourDatabaseName'
```

Answer (score 1):

Necromancing. 
A bit old those row_numbers in CTEs. 
Here more modern SQL:

```
-- Records in restorehistory may be cleaned by sp_delete_backuphistory. 
-- USE msdb; GO EXEC sp_delete_backuphistory @oldest_date = '01/14/2010';  

SELECT 
     dbs.name AS db_name 
    ,dbs.create_date 
    ,dbs.compatibility_level 
    ,dbs.collation_name 
    ,dbs.recovery_model_desc 
    ,dbs.snapshot_isolation_state_desc 
    ,dbs.user_access_desc 
    ,dbs.state_desc 
     
    ,dbs.physical_database_name 
    ,dbs.log_reuse_wait_desc 
     
    ,tRestoreHistory.restore_date 
FROM master.sys.databases AS dbs 

OUTER APPLY 
    (
        SELECT restore_date 
        FROM msdb.dbo.restorehistory AS rhistory 
        WHERE rhistory.destination_database_name = dbs.Name 
        ORDER BY rhistory.restore_date DESC 
        OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY 
    ) AS tRestoreHistory 

WHERE (1=1) 
-- AND restore_date < CAST(FLOOR(CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS float)) AS datetime) 

ORDER BY restore_date DESC, create_date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Destination_database_name, 
       restore_date,database_name as Source_database,
       Physical_device_name as Backup_file_used_to_restore 
from msdb.dbo.restorehistory rh 
  inner join msdb.dbo.backupset bs 
    on rh.backup_set_id=bs.backup_set_id
  inner join msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily bmf 
    on bs.media_set_id =bmf.media_set_id
ORDER BY [rh].[restore_date] DESC
```

For detailed information you can check below link:

http://www.passionforsql.com/how-to-find-when-last-database-backuprestore-was-done/