# Determining Database Restore Date

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server, how can I obtain the restore date for a particular database?

Comment: What database platform & version?

Comment: This is a good question, but I believe all answers below (as of 2019/02/19) only tell when the restore starts but NOT when the restore finishes.

Answer (score 8):

It's a bit difficult to determine exactly what you want from the way your question is worded, but it sounds like this post may give you the needed information

[Identify when a SQL Server database was restored, the source and backup date](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1860/identify-when-a-sql-server-database-was-restored-the-source-and-backup-date/)

From the post:

> After restoring a database your users will typically run some queries
>   to verify the data is as expected. However, there are times when your
>   users may question whether the restore was done using the correct
>   backup file. In this tip I will show you how you can identify the
>   file(s) that was used for the restore, when the backup actually
>   occured and when the database was restored.

Here's the script from that post:

```
SELECT [rs].[destination_database_name]
    ,[rs].[restore_date]
    ,[bs].[backup_start_date]
    ,[bs].[backup_finish_date]
    ,[bs].[database_name] AS [source_database_name]
    ,[bmf].[physical_device_name] AS [backup_file_used_for_restore]
FROM msdb..restorehistory rs
INNER JOIN msdb..backupset bs ON [rs].[backup_set_id] = [bs].[backup_set_id]
INNER JOIN msdb..backupmediafamily bmf ON [bs].[media_set_id] = [bmf].[media_set_id]
ORDER BY [rs].[restore_date] DESC
```

Answer (score 5):

You can find this information easily using [dbatools](https://dbatools.io)' [Get-DbaRestoreHistory](https://dbatools.io/Get-DbaRestoreHistory). Works for one or all databases and supports SQL Server 2005-vNext.

`Get-DbaRestoreHistory -SqlInstance sql2005 -Database db_2005_CL80 | Select -Last 1`

Here's some sample output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the link below:

```
WITH LastRestores AS
(
SELECT
    DatabaseName = [d].[name] ,
    [d].[create_date] ,
    [d].[compatibility_level] ,
    [d].[collation_name] ,
    r.*,
    RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.Name ORDER BY r.[restore_date] DESC)
FROM master.sys.databases d
LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.[restorehistory] r ON r.[destination_database_name] = d.Name
)
SELECT *
FROM [LastRestores]
WHERE [RowNum] = 1
```

[How to query last restore date in SQL Server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33703/how-to-query-last-restore-date-in-sql-server/33705)